# Geolocation.getCurrentPosition() is working but getting wrong coordinates in react native,How to solve this?

Tags: react-native

`navigator.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is not working. It is showing the error doesn't find navigator, but `Geolocation.getCurrentposition()` is working, getting lattitude longitude values, but they are wrong. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`

The Geolocation API exists as a global **navigator** object in React Native, just like on the web. It’s accessible via **navigator.geolocation**.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    location: null
  };

  findCoordinates = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const location = JSON.stringify(position);

        this.setState({ location });
      },
      error => Alert.alert(error.message),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.findCoordinates}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Find My Coords?</Text>
          <Text>Location: {this.state.location}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi am, new to the react native , can u please tell me how to do geofence in react native